# Finding GeographicLib in CMake on Debian

Tags: cmake, geographic-lib

On Debian, I've installed cmake and geographiclib like so:

```
stew@stewbian:~$apt-get install build-essential cmake libgeographic-dev
```

My CMakeLists.txt file looks like so:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(geoexample)

find_package(GeographicLib REQUIRED)

add_executable(geoexample main.cpp)

target_include_directories(geoexample PRIVATE ${GeographicLib_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_compile_definitions(geoexample PRIVATE ${GeographicLib_DEFINITIONS})
target_link_libraries     (geoexample         ${GeographicLib_LIBRARIES})
```

My main.cpp is also very simple (taken directly from examples):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GeographicLib/Geodesic.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace GeographicLib;
int main() {
    const Geodesic& geod = Geodesic::WGS84();
    // Distance from JFK to LHR
    double
      lat1 = 40.6, lon1 = -73.8, // JFK Airport
      lat2 = 51.6, lon2 = -0.5;  // LHR Airport
    double s12;
    geod.Inverse(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, s12);
    cout << s12 / 1000 << " km\n";
    return 0;
}
```

When I run `mkdir build && cd build && cmake ..` I get

```
stew@stewbian:~/src/geoexample/build$ cmake ..
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindGeographicLib.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
  project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "GeographicLib", but CMake did not find one.
```

I think that by default, cmake searches `/usr/share/cmake-3.7/Modules`, but libgeographic-dev seems to have installed its Find*.cmake to `/usr/share/cmake/geographiclib/FindGeographicLib.cmake`.  That's frustrating, but myself (plus everyone who will ever need to compile my code) should be able to use a work-around for this simple case (it wouldn't work so well if I need to also include something like FindBoost.cmake from the old location).

```
stew@stewbian:~/src/geoexample/build$ cmake .. -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH=/usr/share/cmake/geographiclib
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:138 (message):
  Could NOT find GeographicLib (missing: GeographicLib_LIBRARY_DIRS
  GeographicLib_INCLUDE_DIRS)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake/geographiclib/FindGeographicLib.cmake:28 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Now I'm not sure what to do here. I can confirm that libgeographic-dev package installed `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGeographic.a` and `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGeographic.so`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote my own FindGeographicLib.cmake to find this and installed it in a subfolder of my project.  Then I pointed `${CMAKE_MODULES_PATH}` to this folder in my project's `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/modules)
```

I started by adding the one deployed by libgeographic-dev:

```
cp /usr/share/cmake/geographiclib/FindGeographicLib.cmake ./modules/FindGeographicLib.cmake
```

Unfortunately, that didn't work out of the box.  The library was found at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGeographic.so` and the extra `x86_64-linux-gnu` wasn't handled well by the script. It tried (and failed) to find the headers in `/usr/lib/include`.  I made some tweaks to the scripts to also check for this case and now I have a working solution.

The new `FindGeographicLib.cmake` is shown below. My changes are indicated with comments to the right of the applicable lines.

```
# Look for GeographicLib
#
# Sets
#  GeographicLib_FOUND = TRUE
#  GeographicLib_INCLUDE_DIRS = /usr/local/include
#  GeographicLib_LIBRARIES = /usr/local/lib/libGeographic.so
#  GeographicLib_LIBRARY_DIRS = /usr/local/lib

find_library (GeographicLib_LIBRARIES Geographic
  PATHS "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/../GeographicLib/lib")

  if (GeographicLib_LIBRARIES)
  get_filename_component (GeographicLib_LIBRARY_DIRS
    "${GeographicLib_LIBRARIES}" PATH)

  get_filename_component (_ROOT_DIR "${GeographicLib_LIBRARY_DIRS}" PATH)
  set (GeographicLib_INCLUDE_DIRS "${_ROOT_DIR}/include")
  set (GeographicLib_BINARY_DIRS "${_ROOT_DIR}/bin")
  if (NOT EXISTS "${GeographicLib_INCLUDE_DIRS}/GeographicLib/Config.h")
    get_filename_component(_ROOT_DIR "${_ROOT_DIR}" PATH)                     # Added to script
    set (GeographicLib_INCLUDE_DIRS "${_ROOT_DIR}/include")                   # Added to script
    set (GeographicLib_BINARY_DIRS "${_ROOT_DIR}/bin")                        # Added to script
    if (NOT EXISTS "${GeographicLib_INCLUDE_DIRS}/GeographicLib/Config.h")    # Added to script
      unset (GeographicLib_INCLUDE_DIRS)
      unset (GeographicLib_LIBRARIES)
      unset (GeographicLib_LIBRARY_DIRS)
      unset (GeographicLib_BINARY_DIRS)
    endif()                                                                   # Added to script
  endif ()
  unset (_ROOT_DIR)                                                           # Moved below if() statements
endif ()

include (FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args (GeographicLib DEFAULT_MSG
  GeographicLib_LIBRARY_DIRS GeographicLib_LIBRARIES GeographicLib_INCLUDE_DIRS)
mark_as_advanced (GeographicLib_LIBRARY_DIRS GeographicLib_LIBRARIES
  GeographicLib_INCLUDE_DIRS)
```

---

#### Edit (2024):

Debian Bookworm has been out for a while, and that release of debian renamed GeographicLib from `libgeographic` to `libGeographicLib`.  But we can still have a script that works for both versions by using the `NAMES` part of `find_library()`

```
# Look for GeographicLib
#
# Sets
#  GeographicLib_FOUND = TRUE
#  GeographicLib_INCLUDE_DIRS = /usr/local/include
#  GeographicLib_LIBRARIES = /usr/local/lib/libGeographic.so
#  GeographicLib_LIBRARY_DIRS = /usr/local/lib

find_library (GeographicLib_LIBRARIES
  NAMES Geographic GeographicLib
  PATHS "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/../GeographicLib/lib")

  if (GeographicLib_LIBRARIES)
  get_filename_component (GeographicLib_LIBRARY_DIRS
    "${GeographicLib_LIBRARIES}" PATH)

  get_filename_component (_ROOT_DIR "${GeographicLib_LIBRARY_DIRS}" PATH)
  set (GeographicLib_INCLUDE_DIRS "${_ROOT_DIR}/include")
  set (GeographicLib_BINARY_DIRS "${_ROOT_DIR}/bin")
  if (NOT EXISTS "${GeographicLib_INCLUDE_DIRS}/GeographicLib/Config.h")
    get_filename_component(_ROOT_DIR "${_ROOT_DIR}" PATH)
    set (GeographicLib_INCLUDE_DIRS "${_ROOT_DIR}/include")
    set (GeographicLib_BINARY_DIRS "${_ROOT_DIR}/bin")
    if (NOT EXISTS "${GeographicLib_INCLUDE_DIRS}/GeographicLib/Config.h")
      unset (GeographicLib_INCLUDE_DIRS)
      unset (GeographicLib_LIBRARIES)
      unset (GeographicLib_LIBRARY_DIRS)
      unset (GeographicLib_BINARY_DIRS)
    endif()
  endif ()
  unset (_ROOT_DIR)
endif ()

include (FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args (GeographicLib DEFAULT_MSG
  GeographicLib_LIBRARY_DIRS GeographicLib_LIBRARIES GeographicLib_INCLUDE_DIRS)
mark_as_advanced (GeographicLib_LIBRARY_DIRS GeographicLib_LIBRARIES
  GeographicLib_INCLUDE_DIRS)
```

Comment: You should append to CMAKE_MODULE_PATH:
`list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/modules)` so it doesn't overwrite existing values.

Answer (score 6):

Workaround for downstream projects: add

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH};/usr/share/cmake/geographiclib")
```

just before `find_package(GeographicLib REQUIRED)`. This fixes the broken Debian/Ubuntu installer. Other distros may put the files elsewhere, though...

Comment: At least Ubuntu 18.04 has already fixed the CMake find module to be also able to find libraries in the `x86_64` subfolder... That was one part of the original problem. The other part - nonstandard location of the cmake file - is resolved by the line I've posted.

Answer (score 5):

According to this [Bug Report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/geographiclib/+bug/1805173),

> The geographiclib-dev installer puts the FindGeographicLib.cmake file in:
>   /usr/share/cmake/geographiclib/FindGeographicLib.cmake
>
> The correct location is:
>   /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules

Indeed it depends by the version of cmake currently installed. In Ubuntu 18.04, it's 3-10.

So you can fix the issue this way:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/cmake/geographiclib/FindGeographicLib.cmake /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/
```